# C++ Loop object "pairs" with one in common

Tags: c++, object

I could not think of a better name.

I have a class called `MoveObjects` which holds position and move info.

Then I have two classes, `Items` and `Attacks`. Both have `MoveObjects` in common.

What I am trying to do, is loop through move objects and the loop determine if it is associated with a `Item` or `Attack`.

Basically (but can't do it this way)

```
// Classes, boiled down, looks like:

  MoveObjects {
    int x;
    int y;
  };

  Items {
    string name;
    int buff;
    int cost;
    int img_id;
  };

  Attack {
    int owner;
    int strength;
    int speed;
  };


// Polymorphism boiled down

  class Item : public MoveObjects

  class Attack : public MoveObjects


// pseudo loop

  for (int i = 0; i < MoveObjects.size; i++) {

    // if item

    // if attack

  }
```

Comment: Try to look up "virtual methods"

Comment: @hoffmale I read up on that and looked at example code. I updated what my code looks like, boiled down, to show how different "items" and "attacks" are. Is virtual methods still the way to go?

Comment: For your use case, it should suffice declaring a virtual method on MoveObjects that gets overridden by Item and Attack. you can then call that method in the loop on MoveObjects instances, and the compiler resolves those calls to the correct method.

Comment: @hoffmale thanks. I have been trying to wrap my head around this, and can't figure out how to write this. So in `MoveObjects` what should the virtual function do? I keep thinking position... but that's not right. I'm confused, the only way I see it is making both a `virtual Item` and `virtual attack` in MoveObjects... that is definitely not right...

Comment: If you desire an answer which is more suitable for soft real-time games, you may want to visit the Gamedev StackExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm writing this as an answer since it's too long for a comment)

Here's a sample layout for using virtual methods to solve your problem:

```
class MoveObjects {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0; // declare a method name
    // other members of MoveObjects
};

class Item : public MoveObjects {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() {
        // insert Item-specific code here
    }
    // other Item members
};

class Attack : public MoveObjects {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() {
        // insert Attack-specific code here
    }
};
```

Basically, you declare a method in `MoveObjects` called `doSomething()` and specify that it will be implemented in the derived classes (in this case, `Item` and `Attack`).

In the for loop (assuming `moveObjects` is of type `std::vector<MoveObjects*>` or similar) you just call `doSomething()` on the base class, which then redirects to the actual implementation of the `doSomething()` method of the corresponding type (`Item::doSomething()` for objects of type `Item`, `Attack::doSomething()` for objects of type `Attack`):

```
for(int i = 0; i < moveObjects.size(); i++) {
    moveObjects[i]->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: one last question. Would it be bad practice to do something like: `GetObjectType()`, returning an enum like, "Item, Attack, Enemy". Then having virtual pointers as: `virtual Item* GetItemPtr(); virtual Attack* GetAttackPtr(); virtual Coin* GetCoinPtr()`. Setting all three NULL by default, and when used, add the pointer to its type? (Ex: So if `GetObjectType()` is Item, GetItemPtr() will point to an Item, leaving Attack and Coin still NULL)

Comment: @EvanCarslake Look up "tell, don't ask". `GetObjectType()` breaks encapsulation. Rather than just calling `doSomething()` now `MoveObjects` has to have knowledge of what's being moved. It must test every case of an enum. It may require access to other internal information in Item, Attack, or Enemy objects. Now you can't add "Goal, Heal, Friend" without having to make changes in previously tested code. That violates the open-closed principle. You'll probably see a lot of procedural code that violates these principles in your time. Study the principles to learn the cost this comes at.

Comment: @CandiedOrange definitely looking up. Also, I didn't know GetObjectType() was already a function. I was thinking of making my own like: `enum MOVEOBJ_TYPE { MOVEOBJ_ITEM, MOVEOBJ_ATTACK }` and a `MOVEOBJ_TYPE GetMoveObjectType()` I also read that the pointers would not be virtual (no such thing.) So essentially I would have all NULL pointers, except the one pointing to its "move object type."

Comment: @Evan I could design a house with 3 outside doors.  When the house is clean you go in door number 1.  If you go in 2 or 3 you get burned to death.  If it's dirty you go in door number 2.  If you go into 1 or 3 you get burned to death.  If the house is cluttered you go in 3.  1 or 2 will burn you to death.  Now sure, we could install windows and peep holes so you have a better than 1/3rd chance to live but does this sound like a good way to design a house?

Comment: @CandiedOrange yeah you're exactly right. I ended up putting it on paper and realizing that my idea would completely defeat the purpose of virtual functions.